# Prevent SVN restore when user no longer has access rights

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

My team is using Visual SVN Server and Tortoise SVN in a Win 7 environment.  We have approx. 10 users who have checked out the whole SVN repositiory on their computers.  We now want to restrict some of those users from seeing a particular file.  In Visual SVN Server these users have been given No Access to the file.  The file in question has been deleted from the computers of the users who should no longer see it (but not from SVN itself as it is still needed by some other users).  **The problem is when a user with No Access rights does an update the file gets restored**.  Is there any way to prevent a file being restored when the requesting user no longer has permission to access?

Please note that setting No Access does prevent the user from checking in changes to the file, and the user cannot get any updated versions of the file that are subsequently checked in by other users.  But they can restore the version of the file they last obtained before losing access - which is what we want to avoid.  Thanks in advance for any ideas.